# What new technologies are HFT or sell-side algo firms using along-side or within CEP engines/platforms?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, cep

For institutional-level deployment (PTF or sell-side algo market making), what new technologies are firms currently using along-side or within CEP engines/platforms to build and generate signals? There is a lot of information on some of the platforms below, but most of it seems a bit dated (2011/2012-ish)

**CEP engines/platforms**

- Streambase
- Apama
- Esper + Storm
- Any others? IBM Streams? Sybase? StreamInsights?

**Statistical Analysis/Machine Learning integrations..**

- Matlab
- R
- Python
- Java / C++ plugins
- Any others?

Thanks